# Gatsby jquery slick $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gatsby, slick.js

I have a problem with gatsby 5, it imports jquery and slick.js to it using "Helmet" without refreshing the page, the script works but as soon as I click f5 (clear the cache), I suddenly get an error that "$ is not defined" or that "jquery s not defined"I feel that it may be a fault that they will not load in the correct js order, but I might be wrong. Will you help?

```
export function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Simtopia</title>
      <Helmet>
      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
         <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
           <script
      src="/js/localJS.js"
    ></script>
 </Helmet>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading scripts that are mutually dependent I'd recommend using the [`Script` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/) that Gatsby provides, which exposes an `onLoad` callback:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Script } from "gatsby";

export function Head() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
      />
      {loaded && (
        <Script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" />
      )}
      {loaded && (
        <Script src="/js/localJS.js" />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

*Note: tweak the order or the conditions accordingly*

---

## ⚠️

Outside the scope of the question: don't import jQuery inside React apps, or you will break the hydration. Really, don't do it.

React (so Gatsby) creates and manipulates a virtual DOM (vDOM) while jQuery manipulates directly the real DOM. Using both will cause unwanted (re)hydration issues because when something changes in the DOM React won't be aware and vice-versa. This translates into multiple issues, but one of the most typical is finding unstyled parts of the page, non-rendered hooks when moving forward/backward using browser's arrows/history, etc.

From [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-dom-manipulation-plugins):

> React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It
> determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if
> the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets
> confused and has no way to recover.

Alternatively, use React-based approaches such [Reack Slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) or using `useRef` hook when pointing DOM elements